# Why is Jenkins caching my old broken Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, bitbucket

I have pushed several updates, which actually shows in the changes in jenkins, but the error still shows the same error message when the first Jenkinsfile caused the error.

example:

```
Started by an SCM change
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git git@bitbucket[myserver]/jenkins_docker.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 2: Expected an agent @ line 2, column 3.
     agent {
     ^

WorkflowScript: 2: No agent type specified. Must be one of [any, docker, dockerfile, label, none] @ line 2, column 3.
     agent {
     ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
```

My jenkinsfile is now updated to look like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label: 'nodejs10'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        echo 'Testing...'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it's not caching. I realised my mistakes.

1. I had the nodejs plugin installed but I hadn't configured node10 in the global tool configurations for nodejs plugin:

   - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin
2. Also I was calling it wrong. I have now changed agent to 'any', and followed the instructions on this artcile as below:

   - https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-starting-with-pipeline-doing-a-node-js-test-72c6057b67d4

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {nodejs "nodejs10"}
// stuff here...
}
```

this works. Though I now have a different issue with npm not installing, but that is now in a separate quesiton.